# TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out why i get the error message

```
TypeError                                 
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I have this code
`

```
df_dur=user.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).sum(['Duration'])
df_dur=df_dur.duration
print('DF Duration:\n', df_dur)`
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message, however I'm not sure this at all is relevant to your question. But maybe someone else will find it useful, I updated my pandas from 0.22 to 1.1 and it solved my problem (TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given).

> pip install --upgrade pandas

NOTE: This was on a Jetson AGX Xavier running tegra linux.

Answer (score 1):

Move the name call out side the `sum` function

```
df_dur = user.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False)['Duration'].sum()
print('DF Duration:\n', df_dur)
```